L in NP and L is coNP-hard=>NP = coNP
How can I prove this:
given this 2 sentences 1 <=> 2:

There exists a language L ∈ NP that is coNP-hard.
NP=coNP.

the direction from 2 to 1 I can prove using the concept of NP-cpmplete and etc. but I dont have idea for the 1=>2
I thought about the concept of reduction sentence but I think its true only for P class:
Polynomical reduction from lanauge to NP lanauge

From 1, we have $\forall L'\in coNP,L'\le_PL$ and $L\in NP$. We conclude that $coNP\subseteq NP$ because we now have a polynomial time nondeterministic TM to a language $L'$ in $coNP$, via $L$'s one.
Finally, we need to show that $coNP\subseteq NP\implies NP=coNP$. For $A\in NP$, we have $\bar{A}\in NP$, so $A$ is also in $coNP$, which implies that's $NP\subseteq coNP$. Thus $NP=coNP$.
